# Build JSON Array through Loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to build a `JSON` array through a loop where the `input` className and value will be used as `JSON` obj and key. But I cannot create one and can't find information on how to create one. I have given a sample below and I need help in the commented line and I want the `console.log(json_array);` to return `{"class_1":"val_1", "class_2":"val_2", "class_3":"val_3", "class_4":"val_4", "class_5":"val_5"}`. How can I generate `JSON` array like this? Also is it even possible to make a `JSON` array through this method?

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    var json_array = [];
    document.querySelectorAll("div input").forEach(x => {
        json_array.push(x.className.toString() : x.value.toString()); // DOESN'T WORK
    });
    console.log(json_array);
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="class_1" value="val_1">
        <input type="text" class="class_2" value="val_2">
        <input type="text" class="class_3" value="val_3">
        <input type="text" class="class_4" value="val_4">
        <input type="text" class="class_5" value="val_5">
    </div>
    <button>BUILD</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your desired output of `{"class_1", "val_1", "class_2",` is invalid syntax. Objects need key-value pairs. An array is not the same thing as an object. If you want an array (values only, no key-value pairs), use an array instead of an object.

Comment: Just change the `:` to a comma to push multiple items to an array in a single `.push`

Comment: I think what people are trying to say is that you're wanting to push an object into the array, you would do so like:
`json_array.push({ name: x.className.toString(), value: x.value.toString() });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object` doesn't have `push`, that's an Array function, you need to add the keys using the bracket notation : `json_array[x.className] = x.value`

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    var json_array = {};
    document.querySelectorAll("div input").forEach(x => {
        json_array[x.className] = x.value
    });
    console.log(json_array);
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="class_1" value="val_1">
        <input type="text" class="class_2" value="val_2">
        <input type="text" class="class_3" value="val_3">
        <input type="text" class="class_4" value="val_4">
        <input type="text" class="class_5" value="val_5">
    </div>
    <button>BUILD</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no such thing called bracket notation.

Comment: @Ele [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) *Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using the dot notation or the *bracket notation* .*

Comment: Ooop sorry, I saw something else... My bad!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want just one JSON object you have to set the keys:

```
var json_array = {};
//...
json_array[x.className] = x.value;
```

Comment: `JSON object` doesn't exist in the js world.  Did you mean `js object`?

Comment: @Ele: It is referring to the output, which can either be one object or an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    var json_array = [];
    document.querySelectorAll("div input").forEach(x => {
        json_array.push({x.className.toString() : x.value.toString())}); // DOESN'T WORK
    });
    console.log(json_array);
};
```

I think everyone on here is still trying to guess the specific shape of your desired result because what you laid out doesn't make sense for a few reasons. My best guess of what you're actually looking for is this...

```
 [
    {"class_1":"val_1"}, 
    {"class_2":"val_2"}, 
    {"class_3":"val_3"}, 
    {"class_4":"val_4"}, 
    {"class_5":"val_5"}
]
```

which would be an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), with input field `className` as the object's key and input `value` as that keys value. If you're trying to achieve something else then let me know.

If what you're actually looking for is a single [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) with input field `className` as a key and input `value` as that keys value, like this...

```
{
    "class_1": "val_1", 
    "class_2": "val_2", 
    "class_3": "val_3", 
    "class_4": "val_4", 
    "class_5": "val_5"
}
```

Then this is how you could achieve that...

```
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    var js_obj = {};
    document.querySelectorAll("div input").forEach(x => {
        var className = x.className.toString(),
            value = x.value.toString();
        js_obj[className] = value;
    });
    console.log(js_obj);
};
```

Comment: It's better to include an explanation of the code as well, rather than just pure code.

Comment: @JackBashford Definitely agree. I generally get the *code answer* out first and then update with the description right after. Is that a *faux pas*? Don't want to violating best-practices, just find its mess to do everything at one in these editors.

Comment: I agree, and it also gives you a chance to experiment with the code you posted (e.g. optimise it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to `push` an object with [dynamic property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
json_array.push({[x.className.toString()]: x.value.toString()});
```

Demonstration:

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  var json_array = [];
  document.querySelectorAll("div input").forEach(x => {
    json_array.push({
      [x.className.toString()]: x.value.toString()
  });
  console.log(json_array);
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="class_1" value="val_1">
    <input type="text" class="class_2" value="val_2">
    <input type="text" class="class_3" value="val_3">
    <input type="text" class="class_4" value="val_4">
    <input type="text" class="class_5" value="val_5">
  </div>
  <button>BUILD</button>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want an *object* however, use bracket notation to add properties:

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  var json_array = {};
  document.querySelectorAll("div input").forEach(x => {
    json_array[x.className.toString()] = x.value.toString();
  });
  console.log(json_array);
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="class_1" value="val_1">
    <input type="text" class="class_2" value="val_2">
    <input type="text" class="class_3" value="val_3">
    <input type="text" class="class_4" value="val_4">
    <input type="text" class="class_5" value="val_5">
  </div>
  <button>BUILD</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`computed-property-names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and you should wrap the key-value pair `{[x.className.toString()] : x.value.toString()}` as follow:

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    var json_array = [];
    document.querySelectorAll("div input").forEach(x => {
        json_array.push({[x.className.toString()] : x.value.toString()}); // DOESN'T WORK
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
    });
    console.log(json_array);
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="class_1" value="val_1">
        <input type="text" class="class_2" value="val_2">
        <input type="text" class="class_3" value="val_3">
        <input type="text" class="class_4" value="val_4">
        <input type="text" class="class_5" value="val_5">
    </div>
    <button>BUILD</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this provide what you are looking for? 
Using an `Array.map` to transform you element collection.
Tweaked based on Ele suggestion of computed property

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {

  let arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div input")).map(x => {
    return {[x.className] : x.value};
  });

  console.log(arr);
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="class_1" value="val_1">
    <input type="text" class="class_2" value="val_2">
    <input type="text" class="class_3" value="val_3">
    <input type="text" class="class_4" value="val_4">
    <input type="text" class="class_5" value="val_5">
  </div>
  <button>BUILD</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this fixed it : `json_array[x.className] = x.value`